# .NET MAUI Environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

Is there a way how to find out that the current environment in .NET MAUI is `development` ?
Because before in my Blazor WASM I did just:
`builder.HostEnvironment.IsDevelopment()`

But in `MauiAppBuilder` I dont see any environment property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approached it a little bit different. I have created `MobileHostEnvironment`:

```
internal sealed class MobileHostEnvironment : IHostEnvironment
{
    public string EnvironmentName { get; set; } = Environments.Development;
    public string ApplicationName { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public string ContentRootPath { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public IFileProvider ContentRootFileProvider { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

then at the beginning of `MauiProgram.cs` I declare and initialize it like:

```
private static readonly MobileHostEnvironment _mobileHostEnvironment = new()
{
    EnvironmentName = Environments.Production
};
```

with a reference to `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;` and before service registering I have:

```
#if DEBUG
        _mobileHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName = Environments.Development;
#endif
```

So that way app in debug is always Development and released one is always Production.

Ofc you can improve this flow by registering it into dependency container.

Answer (score 3):

Well what I usually do for this is I use the if directive

So for instance if I wanna check if wanna set a different value to var in release than in debug I would do something like below :

```
#if DEBUG
var a = "debug";
#elif RELEASE
var a = "release"
#endif
```

Good luck hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've gotten it to work so far is to manually set the variable.  In Windows I set a user environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development and then access it like this

```
var environment = 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

Update
Based on the feedback provided by @Kebechet (thank you!)
I ended up doing it like this. Note: I added an option to the the Configuration Manager dropdown.

```
#if DEBUG
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", 
"Development");

#elif TEST
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", 
"Test");


#elif RELEASE
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", 
"Production");
#endif
```

`var environment =  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");`

Comment: So that you dont have to do it manually you can use `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("name", "value");`